# Ruby/Watir - storing watir objects in hash?

Tags: ruby, webdriver, yaml, watir

I'm new to Ruby, and I LOVE IT.
Playing around with Watir-Webdriver.
I want to store the reference to watir objects in a hash and save it to disk, WITHOUT having first defined the @browser variable.
For example

```
elements = { 
  :home => @browser.a(:href => /home.php/),
  :photo => @browser.img(:id => "photo"),
  :about => @browser.a(:href => /about.php/)
}
```

so that further I can do something like:

```
el = elements
el[:home].click
el[:photo].wait_until_present
el[:about].click
```

obviously this works if I define @browser at the very beginning..

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new
```

but what if I want to store the 'elements' hash as YAML in a file?
Should I store the values as quoted strings and eval them on the fly? like

```
elements = { 
  :home => "@browser.a(:href => /home.php/)",
  # etc...
}

# store elements as YAML file...
# load elements from YAML file

el = YAML::load_file "elements.yml"
eval(el[:home]).click
eval(el[:photo].wait_until_present

# etc...
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify why you want to do this? My guess is that you should probably consider using a page object pattern. An example would be [Cheezy's page-object gem](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object).

Answer (score 0):

Build a [Class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html) to provide access to `@browser` based on your `YAML` config.

Modify your `elements` structure to include the data you need rather than code. Consider this a config hash/file of sorts for your new Class.

```
elements = { 
  :home  => { :tag => "a",   :select => { :href => /home.php/ } },
  :photo => { :tag => "img", :select => { :id   => "photo" } },
  :about => { :tag => "a",   :select => { :href => /about.php/ } }
}
```

Build a class to load the `elements` YAML file and provide access to what you need from `@browser` based on what is loaded.

```
class WatirYamlBrowserSelect

   # To store your config and browser. 
   attr_accessor :elements, :browser

   def initialize elements_yaml_file
     @elements = YAML.load_file elements_yaml_file
   end

   # Retrieve a configured element from Watir Browser. 
   def element name
     @browser.send( @elements[name][:tag], @elements[name][:select] )
   end

end
```

Then when you need to use it

```
# Create an instance of your selector. 
s = WatirYamlBrowserSelect.new( "elements.yaml" )

# Add the browser when you have it
s.browser @browser

# Access the @browser elements
s.element :home
s.element :photo
s.element :about
```

Answer (score 0):

Alister Scott's blog as well as its code in github was the template I used for building all the page objects for a few projects. I think it should solve the repetition issues you described. It also solves the problem of maintaining too many variables for too many pages of objects and keeps objects organized by page and not in a more complex data structure, especially when the number of objects increases.

http://watirmelon.com/2011/06/07/removing-local-page-references-from-cucumber-steps/
http://watirmelon.com/2012/06/04/roll-your-own-page-objects/
https://github.com/alisterscott/wmf-custom-page-object